# Is it possible to share a post automatically on Facebook with FBSDKShareKit?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-share

I want to share a post on Facebook after user successfully logged in. I know how to share the post:

```
let content: FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "http://url.me")
content.contentTitle = "App Testing"
content.contentDescription = "I'm working over app!"

FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: nil)
```

but this code asks the user to click on post button. Is it possible posting a status update automatically how can I do it on Twitter SDK? It just posts a tweet after successful login on the Timeline, I'm looking for an analog feature in FBSDK

Comment: AFAIK it isnt possible to do. The post has to be done by the user action only.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no feature that does this. Your approach would be a violation of their [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control), which includes these rules:

> Obtain consent from people before publishing content on their behalf.

And this may be relevant, depending on what you do:

> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

Comment: Good answer, and well supported. It would likely violate Apple's policy as well. Apple is quite consistent about not allowing developers to post content  anywhere without the user approving it. This is true for mail, SMS, Twitter, and lots of other APIs.